# Запускать cURL поочередно если элементов массива больше N

Tags: php, curl, sleep

Итак, по порядку. CRON каждый день в определённое время должен запускать определённый РНР-файл, который при каждом запуске будет получать с базы MySQL определённые записи и делать с них массив. Количество записей каждый день может быть разное. Если количество оказывается меньше 10, тогда единоразово должен запустится cURL например:

```
if(count($array) < 10) {
    $cr = curl_init("http://somedomain.com/?items=".implode(',',$array));
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     
    curl_exec($cr);
}
```

Но если элементов массива оказывается 10 или больше тогда нужно разбить его на части по 9 шт и последняя часть уже сколько останется. Например если количество элементов окажется 20 тогда разбиваем массив на три части: по 9, 9 и 2 элемента. Дальше запускаем cURL первый раз и с первыми 9 элементами в параметре ссылки `?items=` как указано выше. Потом нужно запустить cURL второй раз со следующей порцией с 9 элементов но через какое то время (время может быть одно и то же для всех порций, как интервал) и так все части.

Должно получится на подобии следующего примера:

```
$array = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20");
if(count($array) < 10) {
    $cr = curl_init("http://somedomain.com/?items=".implode(',',$array));
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     
    curl_exec($cr);
} else {
    $chunks = array_chunk($array, 9);
    foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
        sleep(60);
        $cr = curl_init("http://somedomain.com/?items=".implode(',',$chunk));
        curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     
        curl_exec($cr);
    }
}
```

Не приходит в голову как проверить такой код. Но это опять же набросок, если сразу видно что в нем неправильно или вообще цикл здесь ни причем и т.д. тогда подскажите правильное решение. И чтобы когда все порции отправит чтобы код остановился

Comment: код как код. иф не нужен. просто чанк сделает один элемент в массиве

Comment: А cURL бесконечно повторятся не будет в таком цикле?

Comment: весь массив пройдете, и всё

Answer (score 1):

Например так. Не тестировал.

```
$array = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20");
if(count($array)) { // если есть данные для отправки
    $chunks = array_chunk($array, 9);
    $try = 1;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($chunks); $i++) {
        $cr = curl_init("http://somedomain.com/?items=".implode(',',$chunks[$i]));
        curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);     
        $result = curl_exec($cr);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($cr, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if(!result || $httpCode != 200) {
            if($try <= 3) { // повтор через 30 сек если было не больше 3 попыток
                $i--;
                $try++;
                sleep(30);
                continue;
            } else {
                // обработка ошибки запроса
            }
        }
        $try = 1;
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```